# Error while running command "vagrant up"

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

I am working on Vagrant.
When I run command `vagrant up`, it shows:

```
Command 'vagrant' is available in '/usr/bin/vagrant'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
vagrant: command not found
```

Comment: Did you do something to your `PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of PATH.It looks like your PATH variable got messed up.
Check environment file:

```
sudo vi /etc/environment
```

and make sure file is something like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```